# Don't refresh PATH user environment variable values in ConEmu without Windows reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10, path, environment-variables, conemu

#### 1. Summary

Values of PATH user environment variable don't refresh for me, if I work in ConEmu. I need to restart Windows.

#### 2. Expected behavior

I use [**Chocolatey refreshenv script**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420542/5951529). If I run `refreshenv` in [**Hyper terminal**](https://hyper.is/) or [**Clink**](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/):

```shell
C:\Users\SashaChernykh>zeal
'zeal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\SashaChernykh>refreshenv
Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe. Please wait…Finished..

C:\Users\SashaChernykh>zeal
```

Zeal successful run for me.

#### 3. Actual behavior

In ConEmu:

```shell
C:\Program Files\Far Manager>zeal
'zeal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\Far Manager>refreshenv
Refreshing environment variables from registry for cmd.exe. Please wait…Finished..

C:\Program Files\Far Manager>zeal
'zeal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

#### 4. Steps to reproduce

I download [**Zeal program**](https://zealdocs.org/) via [**Chocolatey**](https://chocolatey.org/) → I add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zeal` —— path to `zeal.exe` in my User environment variable via [**Rapid Environment Editor**](https://www.rapidee.com/en/about):

[image: RapidEE]

→ <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>.

I get expected behavior for Clink and Hyper and actual behavior for ConEmu.

#### 5. Not helped

1. [**Refreshenv Chocolatey script**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420542/5951529),
2. [**`explorer.exe` restart**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5970-explorer-exe-process-restart-windows-10-a.html),
3. [**Close all windows and tabs of all my terminals**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17046730/5951529),
4. [**`resetvars.vbs` script**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171737/5951529),
5. [**`ConEmuC /export PATH`**](https://superuser.com/a/527948/572069).

#### 6. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer restart Windows. It takes a lot of time.

#### 7. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**ConEmu:**
170118 [64]
{Far} mode

Comment: Just a comment: For what you're trying to do (and seeing all the other path entries you have), an App Paths key would be better I suspect. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-133-App-Paths.

Answer (score 7):

For me its OK just if I close all `conemu.exe` or `conemu64.exe` (or even `conhost.exe` or `cmd.exe` if any, but they shouldn't affect ConEmu) processes and then just start ConEmu, take a look:

[image]

But note **one important thing**:

> If you start ConEmu(or any other program) from **another program** like launcher or by hot-key created by **another program** or even by mouse gesture(using something like Strokes Plus) you need to **restart that program** to make that program to receive new environment variables/values, which will be given to child programs, you can see which are child processes and which are parent ones in program like Process Explorer or Process Hacker.
>   So in order to child receive right environment variables/values you need to restart its parent(**if you call child from parent**).

Comment: Blade Might, thanks for answer! 2 questions. **1)** Why in ConEmu don't work `refreshenv` command like other terminals? Is any way, that it works? **2)** Your method don't work for me, if I run ConEmu via [**ConEmu Sublime Text package**](https://github.com/tianjianchn/Sublime_ConEmuOpen). I run ConEmu via Sublime Text package → I change my environment variable use `setx` → I close ConEmu and Sublime Text → I run ConEmu via Sublime Text package → environment variable don't change for me. Thanks.

Comment: **1)** It actually works for me... **2)** Following exactly what you said it works for me too... Maybe your Sublime Text(or ConEmu) stays in memory(or tray), or something like that?

Comment: `Maybe your Sublime Text(or ConEmu) stays in memory(or tray), or something like that? ` — I check — I don't have Sublime Text and ConEmu process, if I reproduce the problem. // You use ConEmu in Far mode?

Comment: `You use ConEmu in Far mode?` Yes and No. But in gif above - No. **1)** Here how refresh env works for me: http://uploads.ru/sx1jE.gif
Script i used: 
https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/master/src/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd

Comment: I use Autohotkey to start cmder (which is a wrapper of ConEmu) and met the same problem.
The solution is quit the ahk script and start it again.
Now the %PATH% variable is updated.

Answer (score 0):

In Win 11 (I haven't confirmed in prior versions of Windows), if you use Control Panel to update the value and save it (search the keyword path in control panel if you don't know were it is) then open a command prompt and execute the command that relies on the PATH and you'll find it has updated.

If not, keep in mind command prompt windows which were open before the change was made will not be updated. Close any previously open Command Prompt windows and open a new one.
You can of course confirm by typing PATH (in UPPER or lower case) and you should see the full PATH environment variable contents displayed.
Image of Control Panel with keyword PATH entered in search bar:
[image: Image of Control Panel with keyword PATH entered in search bar]

Answer (score 0):

Create this user settings ConEmu file:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\.conemu\CmdInit.cmd"
```

Put this code in the file **CmdInit.cmd**:

```
:: Retrieve User & System PATHS from the registry
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v Path ^| find "Path"') do set USER_PATH=%%B
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path ^| find "Path"') do set SYS_PATH=%%B

:: Merge PATHS with ConEmu's PATH
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDir%\Scripts;%USER_PATH%%SYS_PATH%"
```

Now every time ConEmu runs it will update the paths.

**Docs:**
[ConEmu Configuring Cmd Prompt](https://conemu.github.io/en/CmdPrompt.html)